# Does using "greater than" on a partition key on an azure table storage result in a full table scan?

Tags: azure-table-storage

I currently work with a table storage which might soon contain billions of entities. Would a query like `PartitionKey gt 'KnownExclusiveStartPartition'` result in a table scan or can Azure table storage find the result fast using the index?

A follow-up question would be if this kind of behaviour (which queries would result in a table scan and what kind of queries are efficient) is documented somewhere? I know that querying using exact partitions (or even partition+row) values is the best option but details about how the entities are indexed internally would be nice.

Is a table like follows (or something similar) documented somewhere:
*Big O is just my guess what it would take to find the Top 1 value*

- `PartitionKey eq 'X' and RowKey eq 'Y'` -> O(1)
- `PartitionKey eq 'X'` -> O(1) ?
- `PartitionKey gt 'X'` -> O(1) ? <-- Example from my initial question
- `PartitionKey lt 'X'` -> ?
- `PartitionKey gt 'X' and RowKey lt 'Y'` -> ?

Comment: Please check the answer below, and let me know if you have more concerns.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the PartitionKey in the query, then this is at least a [partition scan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide#how-your-choice-of-partitionkey-and-rowkey-affects-query-performance)(it depends on how the RowKey is used in the query) regardless of you're using `gt` or `eq` operators for PartitionKey.

Unless no PartitionKey is specified, then it's a table scan.

For "Is a table like follows (or something similar) documented somewhere", there is no docs to reflect on this.